# Should I be using a T-test to validate logarithmic data?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

To start, I am a geologist, not a stats person by education, so I apologize in advance for anything I get wrong here. I will try to include as much info as I can to help answer this question, but I am more than happy to elaborate on anything that needs further clarification.

**Background:**

I am testing a dataset for allometry, which is the idea that certain parts of a body (or in this case, a glacial landform) are growing faster than the whole.

For data inputs, I started with the length, width, and height of ~300 glacial landforms. The landforms were handpicked by me from a specific area in a mountain range. They represent all the landforms in this specific region of the mountain range, but not all the landforms over the whole range.

I then calculated volume ($l * w * h$) and the "size" ($v^{1/3}$), which is the value used in allometric equations to represent the whole. I calculated the natural log of each variable ($l, w, h, s$) and perform a linear regression on each variable compared to size to estimate how much each variable contributes to size over the whole dataset. In a perfect system, the slope of each of these lines would be 1, meaning that $l, w,$ and $h$ all contribute equally to the size of the landform.

**Statistics proof:**

There are a few data subsets that I interested in where the slopes stray significantly from 1, but I want to check the logic I am using to prove the subset is statistically significant from the whole.

To start, I isolated the subset from the rest of the data (i.e. Group 1 = subset, group 2 = whole - subset).

I then used Excel Analysis ToolPak to perform a T-test: Two-Sample Assuming Unequal Variances on the log data for l, w, h, and size for Group 1 and Group 2 with an alpha of 0.05. I believe that by default the null hypothesis is that the variable means are even.

A sample output looked like this:

|  | Group 1 | Group 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 2.779 | 2.991 |
| variance | 0.047 | 0.035 |
| observations | 291 | 16 |
| Hypothesized mean diff | 0 |  |
| df | 17 |  |
| t-stat | -4.35 |  |
| P(T<=t) one-tail | 0.0002146 |  |
| t Critical one-tail | 1.739 |  |
| P(T<=t) two-tail | 0.000429 |  |
| t Critical two-tail | 2.110 |  |

**Questions:**

1. Am I making the correct choice to perform a t-test here? Is there a different statistical test that would better prove the independence of the two subets?
2. Did I make the correct choice to perform the t-test on the calculated logs of each dataset? Would it be better to perform it on the underlying data before the log calculation? i.e. $l$ vs $ln(l)$
3. The above table shows independence between variable 1 and variable 2, correct?

Any input would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement: "There are a few data subsets that I interested in where the slopes stray significantly from 1"? Was Group 1 defined/known before fitting any regressions? Or is it defined as subsets of landforms where the slopes are very different from 1?

Comment: If the former, you could consider adding interactions to the regression. Something like *log(size) ~ factor(Group) * log(dimension)*. This way you get one coefficient estimate for each group and you can then compare the estimates using [tag:contrasts].

Comment: @dipetkov Group 1 is a set of landforms from a specific ridge where my advisor and I noticed the landforms seemed "flatter" than normal. So we expected the slope to be different from one, then calculated the slope to be different from one, and am now trying to statistically prove that Group 1 is statistically different from the whole dataset I collected. Does this help? Happy to provide more info.

Comment: There might be a danger of a circular reasoning here (but it's also possible I've misunderstood your description): you use the data to find "different" landforms, then use the data to demonstrate that those landforms are indeed different. This procedure is way less reliable than: you formulate a theory about why some landforms are different, then gather data in support of the theory. Here is paper that might be of interest: On wisdom after the event. S Senn, F Harrell. 10.1016/s0895-4356(97)00023-1.

Comment: @dipetkov I see what you are saying. I already had a hypothesis that these landforms were different and why they were different from visually looking at them, before collecting any data.

Comment: Great! Then one way to investigate your hypothesis is with a regression model that includes an appropriate interaction, as I suggest above. It's a more general approach than a t-test.